# Copying Vendor Folder vs. Composer

Tags: php, html

I used composer on my local server for development, and now we want to shift the end product to a web server to make the website live.

Does simply using ftp/copying&pasting the vendor folder work? Or will I have to use composer for installation?

The vendor folder I want to move isn't large by any means.

Comment: Yes it will work.

Comment: *it _may_ works - you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes it works, as far as I know! Kinda defies the point of using composer in the first place though! Have you been editing libraries under the vendor map?

Comment: Good question :D. @Federkun why did you say "but you shouldn't" ?

Answer (score 4):

You can safely copy the vendor folder along with your project, as long as you copy the composer.json and composer.lock files as well.

I've worked with deployment scripts in the past, and what I usually do is run composer install on a staging server, run all pre-deployment tests, and if everything is fine, copy the files to the production server.

Note however, that you should always make sure that the server you are copying *from* has the same installtion as the one you are copying *to*. If for instance the PHP version is different, or some php extension is not present on the production server, the package will be there, but wont run the same as it did on the other server, or might not run at all

Comment: What if you have a different php version or an extensions required by one package is disabled in production? You shouldn't really encourage to do that.

Comment: I think it's some kind of requirements the production server must have to successfuly run your applicaton.

Some applications may be developed on PHP7 using PHP7 features and if you upload it on production server which uses PHP 5.6 or less, these features wont work even if you use composer or copy/paste of vendor folder. Composer will try to download older packages for production PHP version, but may not contain features used by application itself.

Comment: does it matter where i ftp the composer files? 

on my development server, i deleted the composer files to see if my vendor would work, and it did, how did it still work when i removed composer.json and composer.lock? or are these files only used for the initial installation?

Comment: These files are used if you use composer commands (conposer install, update, require, etc). For application, they are not needed (if you dont plan update/install on production).

Comment: so if im just copying the vendor file, i dont need to copy the composer.json and composer.lock cause im not using composer to install right?

Comment: Yep, I think, they should not be at the production as well, just in development environment. As far as if a customer tries to update libraries, they may have an impact on application which will require a programmer to fix the issues. These things should be tested on development first.

Comment: What kind of customer try to update the library? Also, if all the packages don't introduce (mistakenly) any bc break, it's safe to update them. (that's way we follow semver). You don't have to, but you should upload the `composer.json` files as well.

Comment: What kind of customer? You can never be sure, what customer will and won't do. Once, I was developing on Symfony2 framework, I did run composer update and application stopped working because of some things were changed and also needed the change in the application code (it was a long time ago, I don't remember what exactly it was). But if it is needed, then I believe `composer.json` should not be accessible by anyone (for instance, via URL). Showing what extensions and its versions is customer using can be a security issue.

Comment: does copying the vendor files guarantee that the modules are installed successfully?

Comment: @arsenalftw067 It will guarantee that they are installed, but if they have dependencies to, for instance, php extentions that you dont have installed on that server, they wont run successfully.

Comment: I see, it turns out the vendor did work correctly. thank you everyone for your contribution